# Xcode 10.2 restore breakpoint line highlighting when stepping through?

Tags: debugging, breakpoints, xcode10.2

I've had the macOS Mojave turned to dark mode and back a couple time. I'm seeing a weird bug where most of the time my breakpoint debugging no longer highlights the line currently being executed. I get a green bubble saying "Breakpoint" to the right, but the line itself is not highlighted.

**How do I restore Xcode 10.2 not highlighting the lines stepped through while debugging with breakpoints?**

Toggling between different stack trace levels at the "thread" restores highlighting when switching between levels, but within the same level, I lose highlighting as soon as I select anything else, and I don't get the highlighting restored when I click on the breakpoint within the same level.

I would expect to see a faint gray highlight to appear on the same line as the debug bubble (same as cursor at the bottom of the image).
[image]

I would expect to see every time I click on breakpoint
[image]

Comment: If you’ve found an Xcode bug, file it with Apple.

Comment: I was hopping there's some xcode setting I can tweak to get the line to stay highlighted even as I navigate around the source file